# Read Persian argument in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I use of codeigniter.
I have a form which enters values in Persian language. When I submits the form, it called a function in main controller. Then, I want to read the arguments using  $this->input->post(), but I receives their unclear(for example Ø¬ÙˆØ§Ø¯).I have same problem in send a Persian argument from controller to view too.

Comment: How do you check the returned values? Make sure that you have set the character encoding to `UTF-8`. Simply by adding `<meta charset="utf-8">` within the `<head>` section of your HTML page.

Comment: yes I set <meta charset="utf-8">. In controller I print one of aruments(for example echo $this->input->post('txtname'))